# Multi-row cells in Rmarkdown table?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I'd like to add a table to an Rmarkdown document that contains a configuration like this:

[image: multi-row cell from microsoft office]

But none of the [four standard methods of creating tables in Rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#multiline-tables)  in html mode seem to support cells that span multiple rows or columns. Is there some workaround I can use to include multirow cells like this in my tables?

Note that this is different than [Multiple lines in a single cell for rmarkdown table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120954/multiple-lines-in-a-single-cell-for-rmarkdown-table), as I'm not looking to put multiple lines in a cell, I'm looking to make a cell that spans multiple rows.

Comment: If you need that much control, it sounds like you should just be writing HTML for that table.

Answer (score 0):

If Rmarkdown is like markdown, you can (and I think is the only way to do it) insert the table creation code directly in HTML, something like:

```
<table>
  <TR>
       <TD ROWSPAN="4">Type</TD>
       <TD COLSPAN="1">data-1</TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
          <TD>data-2</TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
          <TD>data-3</TD>
     </TR>
     <TR>
          <TD>data-4</TD>
     </TR>
</table>
```